# Backgroundworker - Cannot use generated bitmap after completion

Tags: wpf, vb.net, multithreading, parameter-passing, backgroundworker

Hi I am having trouble assigning the image data that was generated inside my BackgroundWorker's DoWork handler, to an image object after processing is complete. I am getting an error stating that "the calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it". The erroring line is

```
PreviewImage.Source = Bmp
```

My DoWork handler code is as follows:

```
Private Sub QueryForAssociatedData(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BW_DrawSideBarImage.DoWork
        Using Context As New MyContext
            Try
                Dim bmp2 As New BitmapImage
                bmp2.BeginInit()
                bmp2.StreamSource = New MemoryStream(SidebarImageBytes)
                bmp2.EndInit()

                'Dispatcher.Invoke(Sub() PreviewImage.Source = bmp2)

                e.Result = bmp2
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        End Using
    End Sub
```

I expected to be able to expose the created image in RunWorkerCompleted in the usual way but it didnt seem to work:

```
    Private Sub FinishDrawingSidebar(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BW_DrawSideBarImage.RunWorkerCompleted
        Dim Bmp As BitmapImage = TryCast(e.Result, BitmapImage)
        PreviewImage.Source = Bmp
    End Sub
```

I also tried

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(Sub() PreviewImage.Source = Bmp)
```

in DoWork and in RunWorkerCompleted but the same error appears. If I just return Nothing instead of Bmp then there is no problem so I am assuming the Bmp is the object being complained about.

Please let me know what stupid thing I am doing wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as the BitmapImage is still modifiable, it stays associated with the thread that created it.  And using it in another thread will throw the exception you got.

Simple to fix, you need to freeze it so it becomes thread-safe.  Add this line of code to your worker:

```
    ...
    bmp2.EndInit()
    bmp2.Freeze();    // <== added
```

Comment: Brillant, you are a legend! Much appreciated that worked well.